# matcher.find() regex Java function

Tags: java, regex

consider the below code that checks if input is in the form: `<tag>contents</tag>`
If input in above form, print content between the tags else print None.

eg:

1. input: `<h1>Nayeem loves counseling</h1>`
   output: Nayeem loves counseling
2. input: `<h1><h1>Sanjay has no watch</h1></h1><par>So wait for a while</par>`
   output: Sanjay has no watch
   So wait for a while
3. input: `<Amee>safat codes like a ninja</amee>`
   output: None

```java
String line = scan.nextLine();

boolean matchFound = false;
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("<(.+)>([^<]+)</\\1>");
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    matchFound = true;
}

if(!matchFound) {
    System.out.println("None");
}
```

Here find() returns boolean type. My question is why should find() be used with while loop? Why can't I use "if" in place of while? How is find working internally?

Comment: If you used an `if`, the second input example would only print one result (I think). The `while` is necessary if you want to find _all_ the matches, rather than just the first.

Comment: The body of a while loop runs zero or more times; the body of an if statement runs zero or one times. The choice between them depends on how many matches you expect to find.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `find()`, the matcher will attempt to find the next sequence that matches your regex pattern. By using `find()` in a while loop, you will be able to obtain all the matching sequences if there are any. If you want to match the input string as a whole, you can use `matches()`.

Reference:

[find method in Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())

[matches method in Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) for `find`.

> `public boolean find()`
>
> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, *if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match*.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.

The code you are looking at is *repeatedly* finding the next match for the regex and printing its matched 2nd group.  Since the 2nd group of the match is the tag contents, this prints the contents of all tags.

If you used `if` instead of `while`, only the first match will be printed; i.e. only content of the first tag.